# Service method transactionality when not using exceptions as flow control in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have the following method in an `@Service` class which has `@Transactional` defined:

```
  @Override
  public Result add(@NonNull final UserSaveRequest request) {
    final Result<Email> emailResult = Email.create(request.getEmail());
    final Result<UserFirstName> userFirstNameResult = UserFirstName.create(request.getFirstName());
    final Result<UserLastName> userLastNameResult = UserLastName.create(request.getLastName());

    final Result combinedResult = Result.combine(emailResult, userFirstNameResult, userLastNameResult);
    if (combinedResult.isFailure()) {
      return Result.fail(combinedResult.getErrorMessage());
    }

    final Result<User> userResult = User.create(emailResult.getValue(), userFirstNameResult.getValue(), userLastNameResult.getValue());
    if (userResult.isFailure()) {
      return Result.fail(userResult.getErrorMessage());
    }

    this.userRepository.save(userResult.getValue());

    return Result.ok();
  }
```

Now as you can see I utilize a `Result` class which can contain a return value or an error message as I don't think using exceptions for flow control is very clean.

The problem I now have is; the complete method is bound in one transaction and if one database call should fail the whole transaction will be rolled back. In my model however, after the `this.userRepository.save(userResult.getValue());` call, if something would happen that would force me to return a failed result, I can't undo that `save(userResult.getVlaue());` call seeing as I don't use exceptions for flow control.

Is this a problem that has an elegant solution, or is this a place where I need to make a trade-off between using exceptions as flow control and having to mentally keep track of the ordering of my statements in these kind of situations?

Comment: The elegant solution is to use exceptions to signal bugs, like the impossibility to create a User object (why would that ever fail, and what can you do about it anyway, except fixing the bug). Fighting against the framework and the conventions will only make your code clumsy, complex, convoluted and hard to test, read and maintain. The idiomatic code for your method would be `userRepository.save(new User(request.getFirstName(), request.getLastName(), request.getEmail());` One line of stupid simple code instead of your 13 lines of code.

Comment: @JBNizet, I think you're right. I am trying to incorporate a more DDD-style approach whereby the business rules for creation are embedded in the Entity or ValueObject. I can still achieve those things even when using exceptions. I don't fully agree on the part about "what can go wrong creating a User", besides incorrect input from the user (which can be caught earlier) I also think it's important to protect from bad/lazy coding, so those business checks need to be done, in that regard creating a User can easily go wrong. I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: We agree: either the creation fails because the request that should have been validated sooner hasn't been correctly, or because some code passes incorrect information. Failing when that happens is a good thing, but the only thing to do is to signal the bug, and that's what runtime exceptions are for. And bugs should hopefully be an exceptional situation, not flow control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can trigger rollback manually. Try this:

```
TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
```

More information: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-rolling-back

Comment: I've accepted this answer as this is technically what I was looking for. The comments from JB Nizet have shown me that I should alter my general approach. Just to ensure new readers who haven't gone through the documentation don't simply copy and paste, the documentation says `Programmatic rollback is available should you absolutely need it, but its usage flies in the face of achieving a clean POJO-based architecture.`, so beware of that.